# How do you stop/check logs for airflow webserver/scheduler with --daemon?

Tags: airflow

Hi I'm using Airflow and running in background in EC2. 
But how do you stop/check logs? 
I couldn't find the detailed explanation on the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Job/task logs are available via the admin UI. I have given up on webserver logs. I have never seen any output logging when passing logging parameters (`-l`, `--stdout`, `--stderr`) to the `airflow webserver` command.

I do capture scheduler output by launching it as follows:

```
nohup airflow scheduler >> ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs/scheduler.log 2>&1 &
```

The Airflow webserver will create a PID file in the `AIRFLOW_HOME` folder so you stop it with `kill -TERM $(cat ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow-webserver.pid` or use `pkill -f "gunicorn: master [airflow-webserver]"`.

Comment: I also could not get these flags to work very well. They do however only work if you also pass -D when calling airflow on the command line.

Comment: @jhnclvr - Yes, I used -D (especially for the webserver). In airflow 1.8.0 this tends to block for a really long time. The redirects still don't work properly.

Comment: I agree, the logs are still mostly empty. I just couldn't get them to appear at all without -D

Comment: you could specify log file in airflow.cfg with access_logfile and error_logfile.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to find the Airflow webserver logs under `/var/log/upstart/` even though the designated log location was set to `/var/log/airflow/`. I originally thought the webserver process was not producing any logs but turns out it was just in a different location than specified in the config files.

Answer (score 5):

If you start your Airflow-Webserver and other deamon using systemd (see [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd) repo), it`s quite straightforward:

`journalctl -u airflow-webserver.service`

Comment: I get `bash: journalctl: comand not found`

Comment: Then you are not using systemd as your system-process Management-Tool/Init-System but another one. It depends how n your Linux-Distro, for example.